# Summation of Infinite Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n 2^{2n+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show That :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n 2^{2n+1}} = \ln \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

I could show convergence. (I dont need to show that this converges). However I couldn't figure how to show the value.

Comment: Did you try $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{y^n}{n} = -\ln \left(1-y\right)$

Answer (score 8):

There are various options - here is one: I won't work it through to the end.

Write $$f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n 2^{2n+1}}$$

Then $$f'(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n-1}}{2^{2n+1}} = \frac 1 8 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac t 4\right)^{n-1}$$

Which is a geometric series ...

Comment: Good answer! You have to be a little bit careful about the domain of definition of $f$ (because the radius of convergence of $f$ is 4, by the ratio test) but as we are only interested in $t=1$ this is of course no problem.

Answer (score 8):

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{y^n}{n} &= -\ln \left(1-y\right) \hspace{15pt} {\textit{apply }} \hspace{5pt} y=\frac{1}{x^2}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n x^{2n}} &= -\ln \left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n 2^{2n+1}} &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n 2^{2n}} = -\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

Do the rest to simplify and get what you want.

Comment: $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} \Rightarrow f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-x} $$

$$ f(x) = \int \frac{1}{1-x} \ dx = -\ln(1-x) + c $$

$$ but : f(0) = 0 \Rightarrow 0 + c = 0 \Rightarrow c = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}  =  -\ln(1-x) $$

Comment: @what'sup An alternative derivation: Start with$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\dfrac{(1-x)^\epsilon-1}\epsilon$$which L'Hôpital shows is equal to $\ln(1-x)$. Then, use Newton's generalized binomial theorem to expand that into a series.

Answer (score 4):

Artin's comment pretty much answers the question.

> Did you try $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{y^n}{n}=-ln(1-y)$

Just observe that your series actually is $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(1/4\right)^n}{n}$$
As this is homework, you should also, I guess, be careful to check radius of convergence...

Comment: $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} \Rightarrow f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-x} $$

$$ f(x) = \int \frac{1}{1-x} \ dx = -\ln(1-x) + c $$

$$ but : f(0) = 0 \Rightarrow 0 + c = 0 \Rightarrow c = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}  =  -\ln(1-x) $$